Simulate toggle click for tailwind modal popup (Flowbite)
I am using Tailwind CSS (Flowbite). I want my modal popup to automatically popup when a user lands on the page, rather than wait for the user to click the button.
This is my jQuery click method:
$("#mybutton").click();

 $(".mybutton").trigger('click');

This is the modal button and the modal.
 <button data-modal-target="crud-modal" id="mybutton"  data-modal-toggle="crud-modal"
        class="mybutton " type="button">
    Toggle modal
</button>

 <div id="crud-modal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" 
         class="hidden overflow-y-auto overflow-x-hidden fixed">
        <div class="relative p-4 w-full max-w-md max-h-full">
            <!-- Modal content -->
            <div class="relative bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-gray-700">
                <!-- Modal header -->
                <div class="flex items-center justify-between p-4 md:p-5 border-b rounded-t dark:border-gray-600">
                    <h3 class="text-lg font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
                        Create New Product
                    </h3>
                    <button type="button">
                        <span class="sr-only">Close modal</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


The data-* attributes on the <button> element seem to suggest that you may be using Flowbite but you did not mention anything about it – could you confirm whether you are using Flowbite please?

hi @Wongjn. - i am indeed using flowbite.  I will edit my question

I think you're doing it correctly.
Both
$("#mybutton").click();

or
$(".mybutton").trigger('click');

will trigger the modal to open.
You can also use jquery timeout, for example wait 2 seconds:
$( document ).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    FlowbiteInstances.getInstance("Modal", "crud-modal").show();
    // or replace this with the button click
  }, 2000);
});

check Instance manager if you want to access the Flowbite instances.

hello @Choc thank you so much. i am having problems using the global modal = FlowbiteInstances.getInstance('Modal', 'login-modal').show();. i keep getting this error:  Instance with ID login-modal does not exist.

how do i ensure that the global object is available on the page?

Assuming your ID exists, the error means that the Flowbite instance has not yet been created while you are accessing it. The function "FlowbiteInstances.getInstance" should be called after the init process.
